# numpy.where() returns inconsisten dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I pass an array of size (734,814,3) to a function but numpy.where() gives one dimensional result instead of the two-dimensional one, which it should for a 2D array

```
def hsi2rgb(img):
    img_rgb = np.empty_like(img)
    h = img[:,:,0] #(734,814)
    s = img[:,:,1] #(734,814)
    i = img[:,:,2] #(734,814)
    l1 = 0.00
    l2 = 2*3.14/3
    l3 = 4*3.14/3
    l4 = 3.14
    r1 = np.where(np.logical_and(h>=l1, h<l2)) #(99048,)
    r2 = np.where(np.logical_and(h>=l2, h<l3))
    r3 = np.where(np.logical_and(h>=l3, h<l4))
    hs = h[r1]
    return img_rgb
```

r1 is shown to be a tupple, and r1[0],r1[1] are of the size 99048, which shouldn't be the case. r1 should have row indices and column indices of those values which satisfy the condition. I tried it without the logical and, using just one condition, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed your code, and `np.where` returned the expected result: a tuple with two 1D arrays containing the indexes where the condition is met:

```
import numpy as np
h = np.random.uniform(size=(734, 814))
r1 = np.where(np.logical_and(h >= 0.1, h < 0.9))
print(r1[0].shape, r1[1].shape)    # (478129,) (478129,)
```

This means that 478129 elements met the condition. For each of them, r1[0] will have its row index, and r1[1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) will have its column index. Namely, if `r1` looks like

```
(array([  0,   0,   0, ..., 733, 733, 733]), array([  0,   1,   2, ..., 808, 809, 811]))
```

then I know that `h[0, 0]`, `h[0, 1]`, `h[0, 2]`, etc satisfy the conditions: the row index comes from the first array, the column index from the second. This structure may be less readable, but it's usable for indexing the array `h`.

The transposed form of the output is more readable, being a 2D array with row-column index pairs:

```
array([[  0,   0],
       [  0,   1],
       [  0,   2],
       ...,
       [733, 808],
       [733, 809],
       [733, 811]])
```

It can be obtained by transposing `r1` (if you need the original `r1` as well), or directly with [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html):

```
r1 = np.argwhere(np.logical_and(h >= 0.1, h < 0.9))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there an easy way of accessing the indices in this case? Using img_rgb[r1[:,0],r1[:,1]][0] = h[r1[:,0],r1[:,1]] gives broadcasting error "could not broadcast input array from shape (99048) into shape (3)"

Comment: Don't do `array[something][0]` that's not a good NumPy approach and it is a reason for the error here. The original form of `r1`, a tuple, is designed for ease of indexing. `rgb[r1[0], r1[1], 0] = h[r1[0], r1[1]]` is all it takes.